# Is there a way to color a specific word in Placeholder text QML?

Tags: qt, qml

Is there a way to color a specific word in placeholder of text in QML?

I saw you can do it in `TextArea` or `Flow` but I need two colors in a placeholder of a `TextField`.
What I need is something like this: let's say my placeholderText is ("Last name"). I need "Last" in grey and "name" in pink.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried at random to use HTML instead of plain text and that suddenly works:

```cpp
TextField {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    placeholderText: "<font color='grey'>Last</font> <font color='pink'>name</font>"
    width: 200
}
```

But this behavior is not described anywhere and I would not use this workaround in production.